# EMR cluster bootstrap failure (timeout) occurs most of the times I initialize a cluster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I'm writing an app that is consisted of 4 chained MapReduce jobs, which runs on Amazon EMR. I'm using the JobFlow interface to chain the jobs. Each job is contained in its own class, and has its own `main` method. All of these are packed into a `.jar` which is saved in S3, and the cluster is initialized from a small local app on my laptop, which configures the `JobFlowRequest` and submits it to EMR.
For most of the attempts I make to start the cluster, it fails with the error message `Terminated with errors On the master instance (i-<cluster number>), bootstrap action 1 timed out executing`. I looked up info on this issue, and all I could find is that if the combined bootstrap time of the cluster exceeds 45 minutes, then this exception is thrown. However, This only occurs ~15 minutes after the request is submitted to EMR, with disregard to the requested cluster size, be it of 4 EC2 instances, 10 or even 20. This makes no sense to me at all, what am I missing?

Some tech specs:
-The project is compiled with Java 1.7.79
-The requested EMR image is 4.6.0, which uses Hadoop 2.7.2
-I'm using the AWS SDK for Java v. 1.10.64

This is my local main method, which sets up and submits the `JobFlowRequest`:

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.InstanceType;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduce;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.*;

public class ExtractRelatedPairs {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: ExtractRelatedPairs: <k>");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    int outputSize = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    if (outputSize < 0) {
        System.err.println("k should be positive");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    AWSCredentials credentials = null;
    try {
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                        "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                        "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                e);
    }

    AmazonElasticMapReduce mapReduce = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);

    HadoopJarStepConfig jarStep1 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
            .withJar("s3n://dsps162assignment2benasaf/jars/ExtractRelatedPairs.jar")
            .withMainClass("Phase1")
          .withArgs("s3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/20090715/eng-gb-all/5gram/data/", "hdfs:///output1/");



    StepConfig step1Config = new StepConfig()
            .withName("Phase 1")
            .withHadoopJarStep(jarStep1)
            .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW");

    HadoopJarStepConfig jarStep2 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
            .withJar("s3n://dsps162assignment2benasaf/jars/ExtractRelatedPairs.jar")
            .withMainClass("Phase2")
            .withArgs("shdfs:///output1/", "hdfs:///output2/");

    StepConfig step2Config = new StepConfig()
            .withName("Phase 2")
            .withHadoopJarStep(jarStep2)
            .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW");

    HadoopJarStepConfig jarStep3 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
            .withJar("s3n://dsps162assignment2benasaf/jars/ExtractRelatedPairs.jar")
            .withMainClass("Phase3")
            .withArgs("hdfs:///output2/", "hdfs:///output3/", args[0]);

    StepConfig step3Config = new StepConfig()
            .withName("Phase 3")
            .withHadoopJarStep(jarStep3)
            .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW");

    HadoopJarStepConfig jarStep4 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
            .withJar("s3n://dsps162assignment2benasaf/jars/ExtractRelatedPairs.jar")
            .withMainClass("Phase4")
            .withArgs("hdfs:///output3/", "s3n://dsps162assignment2benasaf/output4");

    StepConfig step4Config = new StepConfig()
            .withName("Phase 4")
            .withHadoopJarStep(jarStep4)
            .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW");

    JobFlowInstancesConfig instances = new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
            .withInstanceCount(10)
            .withMasterInstanceType(InstanceType.M1Small.toString())
            .withSlaveInstanceType(InstanceType.M1Small.toString())
            .withHadoopVersion("2.7.2")
            .withEc2KeyName("AWS")
            .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(false)
            .withPlacement(new PlacementType("us-east-1a"));

    RunJobFlowRequest runFlowRequest = new RunJobFlowRequest()
            .withName("extract-related-word-pairs")
            .withInstances(instances)
            .withSteps(step1Config, step2Config, step3Config, step4Config)
            .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
            .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
            .withReleaseLabel("emr-4.6.0")
            .withLogUri("s3n://dsps162assignment2benasaf/logs/");

    System.out.println("Submitting the JobFlow Request to Amazon EMR and running it...");
    RunJobFlowResult runJobFlowResult = mapReduce.runJobFlow(runFlowRequest);
    String jobFlowId = runJobFlowResult.getJobFlowId();
    System.out.println("Ran job flow with id: " + jobFlowId);

}
}
```

Comment: A bootstrap action failure means the cluster is not even completing startup and has yet to run the steps.   Drop the withHadoopVersion, not needed with release label.  Does a vanilla EMR cluster with default settings start using the web console?

Answer (score -2):

A while back, I encountered a similar issue, where even a Vanilla EMR cluster of 4.6.0 was failing to get past the startup, and thus it was throwing a timeout error on the bootstrap step.

I ended up just creating a cluster on a different/new VPC in a different region and it worked fine, and thus it led me to believe there may be a problem with either the original VPC itself or the software in 4.6.0.

Also, regarding the VPC, it was specifically having an issue setting and resolving DNS names for the newly created cluster nodes, even though older versions of EMR were not having this problem